U.S. expat in Korea trying to use Bank of America online banking
I need to access my BoA account, but they require calling their number for a security code
(I have been able to get away with this because my phone was registered as a secure device prior to their change in sign-in policy; sadly, with a factory reset, this privilege is gone now). Initially, I thought of talking to their customer service through an international call to clear the online banking for me, but I suspect they won't allow it if I am calling through a foreign number.
I do have an U.S. phone number that belongs to my aunt, but I have no idea how the BoA security call works. Will an automated service text me back a security code once and I will be set? Will it transfer my call to customer service where I will actually have to talk to a representative? In the case of the former I can simply ask my aunt to get the code for me. But if the latter is the case, it will be tricky as I won't be able to directly talk to the customer service person.
Google search did not yield any clear case with BoA, so if anybody has similar experience dealing with their authentication process outside the U.S., please share with me how you managed to (re)enable online banking. Appreciate it in advance!

Would a USB security key solve the problem?
